# When is the Function keyword needed?

Tags: javascript

I have a function here, inside that function, there's a helper function. Right now my error is pointing to the first bracket of my `display` function.

```
function main() {

// Array of objects
// Sorted those objects

display() { <---Error here

}
}
```

There's an array of objects where I mapped what I needed and sorted them. After that within that same function, this `display` function should show up on the DOM, but am getting `unexpected token {`

What am I missing?

**ANSWER**

Thanks to everyone, I understand where my confusion was. In some instances, specifically when dealing with classes, I saw that the `function` keyword was omitted whenever declaring functions within that class.

That is possible due to prototype inheritance I believe and in any other case the `function` keyword is needed.

Comment: well that is not a function.... missing 'function' or fat arrow

Comment: It should be `function display() ...`

Comment: i agree, but please take look at edit

Comment: A helper function is simply a function that encapsulates some chunk of work for another, allowing you to compartmentalize and make your code more readable. I don't see how declaring a function as `function display()` implies that it isn't a helper function, as it sounds like you were told.

Comment: gotcha, so something like this `display()....` can be done inside of a class but otherwise needs to look like `function display()..`?

Comment: i think i got confused cause in some instances i saw that the function keyword was omitted

Comment: @mph85 Correct. [Prototype methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods) omit the `function` keyword. You may also have seen this syntax in a standard object as a [method definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

Comment: @TylerRoper got it, i understand now. appreciate everyone's feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It dosen't work since `display()` is calling (the non-existing) function display. (you can only use that kind of declaration in an object).

Below you see other ways to declare the function:

```
function main() {

  // Array of objects
  // Sorted those objects

  display() { <---Error here because it is calling a function

  }
  function display2() {
   // this works
  }
  const display3 = () => { 
    // this works too.
  } 

  var display4 = function() { 
   // this wors too, as suggested by Sagar V 2
  }
}
```

**update**

You can omit the function keyword when defining functions in an [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions):

```
const myObject = {
  traditionalWay: function() {
  },
  newWay() {
  }
}
```